# sum of folded normal distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have $n$ iid normal random variables $X_i\sim N(0,1)$, and their folded versions $Y_i=|X_i|$. Now I need the cdf, or the density of the sum 
$$
Y_1+Y_2+\dots+Y_n
$$
or at least a good approximation (better than Markov) of
$$
\mathbb P (Y_1+Y_2+\dots+Y_n\ge A).
$$
I know that for uniform variables there exists the [Irwin distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), so I wonder if there exists an analogue for folded normal variables.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Which approximation due to Markov do we need to outperform?

Comment: the mean of $Y$ is $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ so the probability is bounded by $n\sqrt{2/\pi}/A$

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$, a Normal approximation of $\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ will give a much better estimate than that.

Comment: If $Y=Y_1+Y_2$, then the pdf for $Y$ is $\frac{2 e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$.  That suggests there's no nice symbolic result for the cdf of $Y$ or for pdf's with $n>2$.